# We are not reeking of [code-smell]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

> ```
>              One little problem that confronts you 
>                    Got a monkey on your back 
>            Just one more fix, Lord might do the trick 
>           One hell of a price for you to get your kicks 
>
>                                                   Lynyrd Skynyrd
> ```

That smell? It's [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell).

- 295 open questions, 317 total.
- 40 followers, likely wearing tie-dyed shirts.
- Includes some primo vintage stuff:

  - [How many parameters are too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174968/how-many-parameters-are-too-many), '08, 158 <del>hits</del>, er votes
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240739/boolean-parameters-do-they-smell From back in '09, 54 votes.
  - I could go on, but I got da munchies.

To its credit, the tag is unambiguous, however it's a topic that is, by its very nature, subjective. Not that there isn't a more-or-less unanimous agreement about whether particular pieces of software are odiferous, rather that answers about what to do about them tend to be primarliy-opinion-based. Peruse these questions and you find gems of advice based on experience. However the tag attracts a lot of questions that simply ask opinions, such as  [What is the reason for these PMD rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615419/what-is-the-reason-for-these-pmd-rules), with 6 or 7 opinion-filled answers. Or the whole **"Is [term] a code smell?"** series ([105 in all!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-smell%5D+title%3A%28code+smell%29)):

- [Is too many Left Joins a code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793647/is-too-many-left-joins-a-code-smell)?
- [In Python, is use of `del` statement a code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528403/in-python-is-use-of-del-statement-a-code-smell)
- [Are empty interfaces code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552677/are-empty-interfaces-code-smell)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773500/are-private-methods-in-general-a-code-smell
- [Excessive use of `this` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057425/is-excessive-use-of-this-in-c-a-code-smell)
- [Alternatives to passing a flag into a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107221/at-what-point-does-passing-a-flag-into-a-method-become-a-code-smell)
- [The field must have a documentation header - Style Cop - Code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095390/the-field-must-have-a-documentation-header-style-cop-code-smell)
- [Using a generic type argument in place of an argument of type System.Type. Is it a smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257044/using-a-generic-type-argument-in-place-of-an-argument-of-type-system-type-is-it)
- [Using many dictionaries within dictionaries in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263317/im-using-too-many-dictionaries-within-dictionaries-in-my-code-is-that-a-code-s)
- [Is an Initialize method a code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959486/is-an-initialize-method-a-code-smell)
- [Tying a method to implementation classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637377/does-this-method-violate-solid-or-has-code-smell)

I propose [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) be deodorized. Many of the questions should be closed as Primarily-Opinion-Based. Most of them, though, are relevant discussions of software architecture or implementation details, and appear to be tagged appropriately, so detagging & spot cleaning is all they need.

Bonus: the [grand-daddy of them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them). (Apologies in advance; it's a deleted question.)

Comment: While I think code smell is usually subjective, it can also be tagged for questions with requesting simpler solutions of code segment, algorithm or design pattern, which is less opinion involved

Comment: @amuse I saw examples of that, but at the same time there were usually tags like [tag:design], [tag:architecture] or [tag:design-patterns] which are more descriptive, IMHO. I think it would make sense to build a list of suggested retags to be used during a cleanup. Is that consistent with your view, or were you arguing for retention of [tag:code-smell]?

Comment: Approved: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9554803

Comment: [Did you just edit this tag you want to burninate **into** a question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432492/whats-a-more-polite-word-for-code-smell) I can't imagine that's something you should be doing, even if the question is about the tag and even if it needs attention (I might even be inclined to say the fact that it should be closed could be a reason to **not** edit it, although I'm not sure what the official stance on this is).

Comment: @Dukeling - Yes I did add the tag; I think it already had one or two close votes on it (not mine), but since there is a community of folks paying attention to this tag now, doing so gets more eyeballs on it. (I also edited the tag into a pile of already-closed questions about code-smell, so they can be part of the clean up as well.) By editing them, there is a risk they get re-opened; this is something we've seen during other burninations when tags were being consolidated. There have been similar questions I've close-voted and put out cv-pls requests for; they won't get deletion attention.

Comment: Wait so what happened here? I noticed someone used this tag and when I hovered over it it said "DO NOT USE THIS TAG, UNDER ACTIVE BURNINATION": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251541/elegant-way-to-prevent-namespace-poisoning-in-c/38251954#38251954 And yet, this was 9 months ago? Damn hippies.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: As noted in the answer, this activity got put on hold. The new burnination process is in place, so _someday_ this will resume. Or whatever. Pass the Doritos.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +41/-9. A1 (Progress Answer) +15/-3. A2 (Asking for disambiguation) +5/-4

Comment: (As this was started on a Friday, it'll remain featured over the weekend until Monday in order to reach consensus. If the post gets a lot of support in one direction, then we can end it earlier)

Comment: Please, burninate this terrible tag.

Comment: Looks like this is a bit more controversial than the usual tags, so I will leave this for another day. Also, I deleted the progress answer for now. We can undelete and update the answer if it was decided to burninate the tag.

Comment: Put plainly and simply, opinions aside, good answers refer to solutions which generalize well.  And nit-picking generally covers information which does not directly pertain to good solutions in the general case.  I think the code-smell tag is very relevant when used appropriately in this sense as knowing how to identify red flags in one's habits and or thinking is quite valuable.  Fixing misuse of such a tag is another matter entirely.  Call it an occupational hazard.

And no, I don't spend my time fixing up the site.  Have fun beating me for that.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not sure deleting the progress answer was the correct decision.  I think a lot of people (including me) were voting on it as the 'Burn it' answer.

Comment: @Dan, exactly. It was kinda causing confusion. The contents there had already assumed that the decision was to burninate the tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao if you'd done it on Friday I wouldn't have said anything.  Doing it now is IMO problematic in that there probably are a lot of people who saw the question, voted for what they assumed was the burn answer, and having done so aren't planning to return during the voting period.

Comment: @Dan, I'll certainly take the votes on that into consideration while deciding. (The consensus seems to be tilting in the same direction)

Comment: It was little more than a year past when I, a 40-year veteran of the code-pits, and no shrinking violet when it comes to tolerating the topical trend-o-the-moment outbursts from the young 'uns following behind, heard the five most terrifying words I have ever heard emenate from the mouth of a professional coder. Ladies and gentlemen, for your edification, amusement, and sympathy (I left the job not more than a week afterwards) I present: "Comments are a code smell"
Burn it. Burn it with fire.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring:  Q: +104/-22. A1 (Progress Answer) +32/-6. A2 (Asking for disambiguation) +18/-18. A3 (Saying Yes) +27/-4. A4 (Saying Yes) +1/-1.  The community has voted in favor of burninating the tag.

Answer (score 28):

[code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- The [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) tag is known to contain a large number of popular posts. Please do request a historical lock for those posts, if merited.

## Progress:

The [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=code-smell),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-smell%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-smell%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-smell%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-smell%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192418/burnination-progress-for-the-code-smell-tag)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=306314)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### [Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307009)

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 23):

The [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) tag reeks of Code Review (smelly pun intended). It's generic. Tags need to be specific.

I'm not convinced questions need to be retagged. Keep any useful tags on questions that are suitable for the site in the current form.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a rather well-known concept in programming informally known as "code rot". It refers to the decay in quality of a program during a long period of time. Most typically it happens to programs that originally had a poor design, and then have gotten lots of new features added over time, outside the original specification.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot

I'm not sure if this is the original meaning of the "code smell" tag, but "code rot", as defined in the above wikipedia link, could very well be a valid tag.

- You *can* be an expert in knowing about/dealing with/preventing code rot.
- There may be people who are interested in searching for this phenomenon.
- Given a proper definition, it is an unambiguous term with only one meaning.

In any case, we could probably do with a more unambiguous tag.

Comment: The _concept_ of decaying code is well-known; I'm not so sure that equating that to a tag "code-rot" or "software-rot" would be unambiguous though. Rather, it may be one more imprecise slang term that overlaps with existing tags like [tag:maintenance], [tag:maintainability], [tag:maintenance-mode], [tag:code-maintainability], [tag:maintaining-code], [tag:refactoring], [tag:graceful-degradation], and likely others. Yes - we really could use a stronger, unambiguous tag.

Comment: Code-rot and code design are not on-topic here, though; just like best practices, they're opinion-based. It sounds like a great topic/tag for Programmers.SE though

Comment: Code rot and code smells are different things. Both are established terms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell.

Comment: "Code smell" has nothing to do with "code rot." A code smell is a software pattern that is so commonly associated with bad design that using it should trigger a strong reconsideration about whether the overall approach is a good one.

Comment: What kind of valid questions would you tag with either of these?

Comment: "Is the singleton pattern a code smell" would be a valid question. While it is somewhat subjective, its common practice that you should have a damn good reason to use a singleton because they break all sorts of OO best practices.

Comment: @Shayne wouldn't such a question get great answers just by tagging it with the appropriate language, [tag:singleton] and [tag:design-patterns] ?

Comment: @Luuklag the tags are not going to guarantee great answers, such a question is going to attract unfounded opinions. Singletons are bad because many articles on the web say they are bad so it must be true.

Comment: @Gimby, my wording was a little off. What I had in mind was that using these tags attracted the right people to the question, those capable of writing great answers.

Comment: @Lundin I'll try to check the code-rot related questions personally and see if they are on topic. If many of them are on-topic, we can create a tag for that.

Comment: Update: None of the posts were related to code-rot. Most of them were related to design-patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Kill code-smell with fire.

Opinion about one person's preference over another's doesn't help anybody learn. People could say that

```
Mike::Mike():mike(){}
```

is preferable to

```
Mike::Mike(){
this->mike=mike;
}
```

and call the latter a code-smell, even though it's not "wrong."