# What is the tag [code-statistics] about?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I recently found the [code-statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-statistics) tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-statistics/info).
The tag has no description what so-ever.

Also, it is not clear how on Stack Overflow this tag is any different from the [statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag.

Is there any way to merge these tags? I tried to create tag synonyms but these tags don't seem to get a lot of attention.

Comment: No, those are not synonyms. Code-statistics is mostly used on questions about a metric that is reported by static code analysis tools. And with something in the context of [tag:sas] but not sure what this about. I don't see much of a problem with those tags. We don't need to do anything, no synonyms, no burnination, there are no facts to support the gut feeling.

Comment: @rene I dont understand what you are saying: can you give an example of a question which is about code statistics but not about statistics?

Comment: The burden is on you @Cettt but how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967081/track-changes-in-code-over-time) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957077/project-summary-source-code-lines)

Comment: @rene thank you. Now I understand. This tag seems to misused quite a lot. Probably because there is no tag description in it. If you put your comment in a answer  I would accept it.

Comment: @rene that's plain bean counting. Would it be different if I asked "Count the lines on this file" or "Count the lines between these two string" vs what that question is asking?

Comment: @Braiam I'm in the camp that believes a tag is for those who want to answer questions. Being interested to answer questions related to the statistics as the result of static or dynamic code-analysis is very different from overall statistics. related, yes, maybe they could be retagged to two tags but synonyms: I don't think so.

Comment: @rene I'm in the camp that tags has to demonstrate their worth. These tags, don't even fulfill [your condition](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-statistics/topusers). No one is answering them. The top 3 users (lets ignore the closed question for now) would have answered those git/mercurial questions without the tag. If those answers would been there whenever the tag was there or not, do they really demonstrate interest on the tag?

Comment: BTW, if code-statistics and statistics are supposed to be different, why the newest questions seems to treat them like they are the same?

Comment: @Braiam Most users (including myself) probably think that code-statistics refers to writing code for statistical problems. I never thought about statistics which concerns the code written. However most questions with this tag seem to be about classical statistics.

Answer (score -3):

Both these tags are off-topic. Yes, at some point a programmer writes something that has to do with statistics, but the topic of the site isn't statistics. Any programmer could, in theory, abstract any mathematical function to a code form and still don't understand the statistical interpretation of such function, which is the **hard question** that statisticians answers.

Anyone can answer code that gets you the average, or a logarithmic regression (if they search for the formula), interpreting what the result means or why should they be interpreted that way is what a statisticians answer (also the best way to measure certain thing), but the questions on either tag aren't about that, and [the ones that are](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55051521/792066) are off topic. There's no statistics question on Stack Overflow, but code that happens to represent some statistical function. They don't offer the potential answerers effective information that could indicate whenever or not they would be able to answer the question. In fact, OP should provide the only thing answerers don't have in their MCVE, which is the function they are supposed to write as code (in the cases where the specific function is relevant).

BTW, the only specific topic that falls within what could be acceptable on Stack Overflow is [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell), which includes rene's interpretation of what [code-statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-statistics) is about.

Comment: I smell something burning: *DO NOT USE THIS TAG, it is under an active burnination process: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306314* ... oh, it is a code-smell ;)

Comment: @rene "active"... really?

Comment: that excerpt needs an update ... it lost its needed fuel

Comment: I've kept the link to the MSO post but reinstated its usefulness by updating the excerpt. Have your smell ;)