# Featured MSO Question not in the Featured list on SO

Tags: support, community-bulletin, featured-questions

The [burnination effort for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306314/should-we-burninate-the-code-smell-tag) [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) [is featured on meta:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306314/should-we-burninate-the-code-smell-tag)

[image]

And it did show up on the featured question list before.

But now it got knocked out by a second Hot Meta Post:

[image]

Is this intended behaviour or a bug? (Thats why I tagged both discussion and bug)

Comment: By design. I have seen that when there are over 5 posts featured, then one will be hidden (e.g. when the MSE post about maintenance was featured, only two were shown; now that 3 posts are featured on SO, one will be hidden). Turn this into a bug by reporting that not all the featured posts are shown when there are lots of them.

Comment: I think it is by-design. The community bulletin is heavily cached.

Comment: @double-beep, there are 5, not over 5. So they all should be showed.

Comment: You should blame caching. That is all. https://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @BhargavRao but that doesnt explain it being there, and then disappearing again, does it?

Comment: @Luuklag yeah, the CB acts weird usually...

Comment: ... and now this post itself is a Hot Meta Post, with the [code-smell] question still [featured] and still not listed in the "Featured on Meta" list on the main site, although it's present on the "Featured on Meta" list here on Meta SO.  How meta.

Comment: @BhargavRao, easy fix: remove featured from older posts, aka wizzard. Its already featured 1M+

Comment: Nah, that needs more attention. It is one of the [long wanted requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314294#comment1029878_314294). I month is too less ;p

Comment: The rules for stuff showing up in the CB: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/213575 cc @BhargavRao Note that MSE post don't count towards the limit.