# Would "Has <programming practice> ever gone badly wrong" questions be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I'm wondering if questions about whether a given programming practice has ever been the cause of a large problem, would be on topic here.

Note that when I say "programming practice" I mean a way of using one or more programming languages, not features of programming languages.

So programming practices would include particular [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) or things like [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) but not things like dynamic typing.

I'm fairly certain that any question starting with "What are the worst ways that..." would be considered off-topic, so I would word questions like these in a definitely answerable way. "Has the Singleton Pattern ever gone badly wrong?" is a yes or no question, (which I already know the answer to.) I'm interested in knowing whether a particular technique has a failure mode and how bad it was if so, not in hearing a bunch of horror stories like [this question that was marked non-constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed) produced or making fun of obviously bad ideas.

Comment: doesn't that sound like *way* too broad of a question?

Comment: I would ask about a single specific practice per question.

Comment: It's still super broad, even with a single practice. "has this ever happened" is SUPER broad.  Anyway how is that a "practical programming problem". It's pretty much the definition of a hypothetical

Comment: Using the wrong pattern for the problem means it usually goes wrong. It happens frequently. Until you have your approach you really shouldn't start programming.

Answer (score 24):

> I'm wondering if questions about whether a given programming practice has ever been the cause of a large problem, would be on topic here

This would be off-topic for several reasons including for being too broad a question and being somewhat subjective. It's asking for vignettes but without asking about a specific coding problem that needs to be solved.  Also, any and potentially *every* answer could be equally valid

Comment: Would asking "if using X programming practice to solve Y specific coding problem has gone wrong" be any better?

Comment: @Ryan1729: No, not in the least.

Answer (score 11):

To add to [the answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384829/3956566). These answers could be very broad, they are also open to arguments over opinions. Questions that invite debate around opinions are also off topic.

We recently burned the [code smell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306314/we-are-not-reeking-of-code-smell) and the [designs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320690/we-are-out-of-new-designs) tags. These type of questions would fall into both of these categories.

Considering it's also an 'anti-question'. Asking how can this design pattern go wrong, instead of how does this need to be to work effectively (still too broad). It's like inviting video bloopers of code onto the site. May be entertaining, may be educational, but will be a bottomless pit of answers.