# code-smells - The synonym tag to a tag that doesn't exist (or is burninated)

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

There's a tag called [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell), and it has a synonym called [code-smells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smells) See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1801&tab=popular (it may not work - the tag popularity may go up or down)

[image: code-smells tag]

Clicking that leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell which is a link to [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell), proving they are synonyms.

But here's where it gets interesting: [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) got burninated! [We are not reeking of [code-smell]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306314/we-are-not-reeking-of-code-smell)

So [code-smells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smells) is a synonym of [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell), and [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) got burninated, but [code-smells] still exists! Causing there to be a weird tag which is a synonym of a tag which doesn't exist. Synonym of nothing. What is this weirdness?

Proof of [code-smells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smells) being a synonym to [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell):
Search for [code-smells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smells) at Stack Overflow, and you'll be led to [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) instead. Typical for synonyms.

And beware of the [code-smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smell) vs. [code-smells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-smells) confusion while reading.

Comment: i thought, that all 0 tags get removed quickly automatically

Comment: There are 74 of these kind of stale tagsynonyms: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1408822 we might as well ask a mod to go over that list and remove those useless synonyms.

Comment: @nbk yes, but this is not a tag, it is a tagsynonym. Obviously those don't get cleaned-up when the target is removed from the system.

Comment: @rene So, the tag synonyms don't get buninated when the target does... interesting. Must be because it's considered unethical to burn the target's family too due to the target's fault. I just cannot digest how the database can work when there are synonyms whose targets literally don't exist. StackOverflow has junk things like this littered all over, from useless duplicate questions going over background stories of university students to tag synonyms to weird troll accounts. StackOverflow needs a big manual cleanup and management or else the database is going to Overflow. DatabaseOverlfow ahh..

Comment: Are these really something which is desired to be cleaned up? Are they causing harm (e.g. significant confusion)? Most tag synonyms were added in order to focus tags which were being used by multiple people/questions down to a single specific tag. Keeping the synonyms in place continues the requirement that the target tag be the one which is used/recreated. Keeping them results in having to recreate the burninated tag, if someone wants to create a tag covering that category. That seems beneficial to me vs removing them and, potentially, allowing tag fragmentation again if/when recreated.

Comment: I'm not saying we *want* a burninated tag to be recreated, but that it's better that the burninated tag be the one which is recreated, if/when someone does so, than that one or more of the current synonyms be (re)created as an actual tag.

Comment: @Makyen that doesn't make sense at all to me. The system shouldn't have the synonyms showup on the site while their target is removed. If the mods want to keep track of synonyms that went belly up due to a burnination then that list is better created off-line. Now this record-keeping seems to be done on-site with at least a confusing user experience.

Comment: @rene well, as a mod on another site, I proactively created tag-synonyms from and to non-existent tags for future usage. I don't want them to be removed...

Comment: @AndrewT. You're doing that for future usage, understandable. But this is just a weird [code-smell] tag and a synonym to it that someone created for whatever weird purpose. Any stupid tag or tag synonym which is just there for whatever for no reason must be cleaned up.

Comment: I should also note that from a moderator's perspective (and the system's perspective) burninated tags still exist. Burninated tags are not *actually* gone. Such tags just don't have any non-deleted questions, so the system treats them *mostly* as if they don't exist (e.g. requiring the [tag creation privilege](/help/privileges/create-tags) to add one to a question). For example, moderators can still search for [tag:code-smell], and/or any synonyms, for deleted questions, using "[code-smell] deleted:y is:q", and find the 278 deleted questions with the tag. cc: @rene

Answer (score 9):

After some consideration and feedback from two moderators I've come to the conclusion that this bug doesn't need to be fixed but it still is a bug.

The impact of this bug is really low. Tag synonyms that are orphaned don't show up when you select a [tag on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=code-smells&newstyle=true) and that is its primary use-case for tag selection.

It *is* confusing that these synonymed orphan tags do show up on the [/tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page ([only 68 of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1408822)) and that you can search for them as well. If anything, this might need fixing.

The only reasonable page where all tagsynonyms, both orphaned and not orphaned, are shown is [/tags/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) from which the moderator can do their housekeeping, prepare for synonyms to come, do moderatery things etc.

Foremost I don't want to ask the SE dev team to fix "bugs" that make life of mods a tiny bit more difficult for little to no gain overall. At best it is a nuisance. We can live with this one for another 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: The reason this needs to be gone is not to make life easier but because what is this process of burnination that leaves it's synonyms behind? It may be completely harmless in the short term but in long term, they may cause more bugs and database weirdness. This needs to be fixed at some point. But when, doesn't matter. This may lead to perplexing bugs at SO after 20 years or so.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam it has been this way since 2008. With only 68 cases and a clear understanding from the mods what they use these synonyms for I don't think there is much confusion/ weirdness / perplexing bugs. I've seen worse in the data and that is also still not fixed.

Comment: An Example: Everyone has forgotten about the tagsynonym to nothing - [code-smells]: A new language has popped up, Serial Messaging Electronic Lighweight Lsender, or SMELLs. So a new IDE called Code Smells has also popped up, people want that tag. So it's made, the problem is that it doesn't work! When someone tries to tag a question, it instead becomes [code-smell](and gives an error), when someone tries to search it, it instead shows up for [code-smell] again. SO couldn't find the problem, the dev invested a large amount of time. It was tagged as the most perplexing bug of the century.

Comment: I'm not saying to solve this bug right now and now. I'm just saying this needs to be solved at some point in the future as it may lead to future problems.

Comment: It doesn't need to be solved as the moderators now rely on this "bug". It has become a feature.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam re-purposing of past tags is not an issue. When it pops-up a mod can fix that when warranted. That doesn't need pre-emptively fixing. Tagsynonyms do get fixed when needed, even ones that are still active. It is not a huge issue and can easily be handled on a case by case basis.