# Adding a tag suggests a tag to choose. Choosing it asks to create it (huh?). Creating it says it's too similar to an existing tag (huh?)

Tags: bug, tags

In Stack Overflow, for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70806125/729907) I tried to add tag [org-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/org-table). A popup to choose tags suggested this tag exists and I can choose it. The popup showed that it's been used 30 times.

I chose it, to add, and I got dialog for *creating* it, as a new tag. **Huh?**

I went ahead with that "creation", and I got a message saying the creation was refused because it is too similar to the existing tag [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table). **Huh?**

Trying to add tag [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) indicates that there is **no** SO tag [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table). **Huh?**

The tag [org-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/org-table) *exists in emacs.SE*. Is that why Stack Overflow suggested it to choose for SO and showed that it's been used 30 times? Why would it do that?

And especially, why would it suggest that I choose a tag, as if it exists, and then ask me if I want to create it, and then tell me I can't create it because it's too similar to another tag that isn't, in fact, similar?

*This UI makes no sense to me.*  Not helpful at all.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: +1 I tried to edit your question and had similar problems

Comment: This makes no sense to me, I had no problems just... adding the tag.

Comment: Looks like [the {table} tag was burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304218) some time ago, which might explain the "too similar" message. Still doesn't explain the creation thing though.

Comment: The [tag:table] tag does actually exist. It's on 7,757 deleted questions. The system generally treats tags which only exist on deleted questions as if the tag doesn't exist. Part of that treatment is that to add the tag to a non-deleted question the tag must be "created". However, that doesn't explain the issues you were having with seeing the creation dialog for [tag:org-table] tag, as that tag does exist on 31 non-deleted questions (the 30 questions reported to you plus the question you're asking about, as the tag has been added to that question).

Comment: The burnination process is really bugged. For eg. it doesn't remove any synonyms of the burninated tag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407678/code-smells-the-synonym-tag-to-a-tag-that-doesnt-exist-or-is-burninated.

Comment: @Makyen: *"The system generally treats tags which only exist on deleted questions as if the tag doesn't exist."* Thanks for that info. That approach seems misguided, no? What does it really hope to accomplish? Especially if that's not the only assumption the "system" makes, and the result is a convoluted, incomprehensible, and error prone UI.

Comment: That for most purposes deleted posts do not exist, so the system doesn't try to reason with something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Braiam: I'd characterize such a design as "dumb, resulting from trying to be clever".

Comment: @Drew That summarizes the entire site. I think there's a generational disconnect in the hard-won understanding that clever is a bad word.

Comment: I would say that it's actually the result of laziness. Having to deal with post history of deleted post would be more challenging than simply acting like they don't exist and having a view that only considers non-deleted posts.

Comment: What is an "org table" and why does the tag need to exist on Stack Overflow? Do you mean "org chart"?

Comment: @TylerH: An Org table is specific to Emacs. It has meaning when tag `emacs` is used.

Comment: @Drew Gotcha, so would [tag:emacs-orgtable] or [tag:emacs-org-table] be better? I see there's already an [tag:org-mode] tag. Does that not cover the different objects you can make in an org file in Emacs?

Comment: @TylerH: Maybe; dunno. But why add the prefix `emacs-`? Org mode is huge. Tag `org-table` in emacs.SE has 300 uses, tag `org-mode` in emacs.SE has 5000 uses. Anyway, my post here is just about the crazy UI, not a quest for workarounds.

Comment: @Drew The prefix would be so users mixing up 'table' and 'chart' terminology don't mistake "org-table" for what they want when they are talking about an org chart. If org-table becomes more popular, it could be incorrectly selected any time an asker posts about org charts, since it would show up before org-chart would.

Comment: Re: the issue above, [table] is a bad tag and should not be used. You should not be trying to create it.

Comment: @TylerH: I was *not* trying to create tag `table`. Not at all. Please read the post. I simply mentioned that you cannot *add* that tag, even though the UI tells you that it's an existing tag (and the proposed new tag is (wrongly?) considered too similar to it).

Comment: @TylerH: There's nothing sacrosanct about org charts. That's akin to saying that there can't be a `data-flow` tag because there's a `flow-chart` tag (or vice versa). There are lots of tag names that are similar to others that are unrelated. That's the nature of names, and it's the nature of an extremely widely scoped domain such as StackOverflow. (Now if all of its posts tagged `emacs` were instead moved to emacs.SE, and tag `emacs` were burned, then there wouldn't be such a problem.)

Comment: @Drew That's not really accurate; generic tags often are recommended to be replaced with platform-specific ones. "org table" is so generic a name that it could be confused with "org chart" (because chart and table are terms that are often interchanged), so it makes sense to specify "org table" a bit more, since an Emacs Org mode file's "table" object is _not_ similar to an "organizational chart" whatsoever... it's called "tag disambiguation" and is a very common subject of discussion here on Meta (it even has its own tag!).

Comment: @Drew "*Trying to add tag table indicates that there is no SO tag table. Huh?*" implies you tried to add the tag [tag:table]. If you didn't actually try that, I would recommend clarifying your post.

Comment: @TylerH: As I said, *"you cannot add that tag, even though the UI tells you that it's an existing tag"*. I'd recommend that instead of shooting the messenger SO fix its site. This particular part of the UI, at least, is *clearly* broken.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely caused by an orphaned tag synonym.

There's a tag synonym [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tables) to [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), even though neither of the tags exist.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371843/confusing-error-message-when-trying-to-add-a-blocked-tag) on MSE for a similar but slightly different case, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317928/auto-delete-orphaned-tag-synonyms) for a proposal to auto-delete these synonyms, and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/922774/orphaned-tag-synonyms) for a list of orphaned tag synonyms on Stack Overflow.